# How to change image and text when hover image or text. Only with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, text, hover

I have an issue in HTML and CSS.
I have this code :

```
<div id="menu">
    <span><img src="./images/serveurs.png">Actions</span>
    <span><img src="./images/historiques.png">Historiques</span>
</div>
```

I don't know how to change color of text and source of image when the mouse is over the span.
I say "the span" because I would like to change the source of image even the mouse is over the text (and vice versa).

With this code, I change the color of text but...

```
#menu span:hover { color: #FED766;  }
```

May be I have a bad structure in HTML...?

Comment: You can't change HTML will CSS. Either use Javascript or use a background image.

Comment: Thank you for this response.
In the end, that's what I did but I wanted to know if it was possible in CSS, but it seems not

Answer (score 0):

I make an answer because I finded a solution to my issue.
So I wanted create a menu with text and image. So I used images but it's not the solution. The solution is use to a icon font.
This is what I maked with icomoon icon font.
http://www.lesphotosdejuan.fr/partage_dev/menu_font_icone/menu_horizontal.html

With this HTML Code

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="sousMenuGauche">
    <a class="element_menu" id="menuAccueil" href="page_accueil.html">Accueil</a>
    <a class="element_menu" id="menuDocument" href="page_document.html">Documents</a>
    <a class="element_menu" id="menuConfiguration" href="page_configuration.html">Configuration</a>
    </div>
    <div class="sousMenuDroite">
    <a class="element_menu" id="menuDeconnexion" href="page_deconnexion.html">Déconnexion</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS Code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IcoMoon-Free';
  src: url('../fonts/IcoMoon-Free.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


html { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 0.9em; }

.menu
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #23262F;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-weight: Bold;
}

.menu a { cursor: pointer; color: white; text-decoration: none; }
.menu a:hover { color: #FED766;  }
.menu .sousMenuGauche a { padding-right: 30px; }

.menu .element_menu:before,
.menu .element_menu:after { font-family: IcoMoon-Free; }
.element_menu:before { padding-right: 10px; }

.menu #menuAccueil:before { content: '\e900'; } 
.menu #menuDocument:before { content: '\e925'; }
.menu #menuConfiguration:before { content: '\e991'; }
.menu #menuDeconnexion:before { content: '\e9b6'; }
```

I make this answer hoping help someone who search the same menu

Answer (score -1):

u can use:

```css
.myimg{
    content: url(first.png);
}
.myimg:hover{
    content: url(second.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    <span><img class="myimg">Actions</span>
    <span><img class="myimg">Historiques</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to taken time for your response but I dont' understand this solution

Comment: wada y mean don't understand?)

Comment: just replace `  content: url(first.png);` and `  content: url(second.png);` with your pics and `.myimg` class with your class) and its  done I think

Comment: I don't understand because no picture diplay. I use this code but I not see picture.
With the HTML structure, if I use this CSS code  "span:before { content:url(first.png);" , I see picture but not with your code.